# Can a TVF use multiple CTE statements internally?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cte, set-returning-functions, table-variable

I'm trying to make a multi-statement table valued function and failing due to what I think is a limitation of functions and CTEs.

The intended function defines an input parameter(@Param) and and output table(@ResultTable).

It then executes a complex insert statement involving a CTE into that table variable which is (of necessity) terminated by a semicolon.

I then attempt another complex update statement to that table variable involving a CTE and receive an error saying that "Must declare the scalar variable "@ResultTable". Apparently it has dropped out of scope somehow.

I have used this sort of pattern in the past, so my only thought is that the CTEs seem to limit the scope in some way. Is this a known limitation?

Answer (score 2):

Using the following cobbled-together-example, I'm able to utilize 3 different CTE's to work against the output table variable.  Perhaps you could identify the difference between your process and this simple example?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM   sys.objects
           WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TEST_TVF_CTE]')
                  AND type IN ( N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT' ))
  DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[TEST_TVF_CTE]

GO 
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TEST_TVF_CTE] (@sInputList VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS @OutTable TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
    WITH FIRSTCTE
    AS (
        SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
        )
    INSERT INTO @OutTable
    SELECT *
    FROM FIRSTCTE;

    WITH SECONDCTE
    AS (
        SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC
        )
    INSERT INTO @OutTable
    SELECT *
    FROM SECONDCTE;

    WITH FINALCTE
    AS (
        SELECT TOP 1 'XYZ' AS TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC
        )
    UPDATE a
    SET a.item = b.table_name
    FROM @OutTable a
    JOIN FINALCTE b ON 1 = 1

    RETURN
END
GO

SELECT *
FROM DBO.TEST_tvf_cte('...')
```